# Looking for anyone with Chevtaikin Surname

Tags: birth-records, military-records, russia, birthplace

My father was born 1923 in Penza region of Russia.

His grandfather was Andreas, his father was Demetri and mother Tatania.

His 3 brothers went to war (WWII) and his family home was taken over and papa ended up in Eustonia Prison Camp in Novasibirsk.

Papa escaped and ended up in Schleissheim Displaced Persons Camp where he met my mother. They married in 1947 and I was first born in 1948, then my brother in 1950.

We got sponsorship by a Russian friend in NY, USA and we arrived 2/22/1952.

We have more family here in America now. I lost being able to speak German when my mother passed away and I never really learned Russian once coming to America at age 5.

How can we locate any Chevtaikin's in Europe?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History StackExchange. In accordance with our policy about naming people born in the last 100 years (https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I've removed the names of people born before before 1920 from your post. However, it is still avery broad question that doesn't fit well within our site -- can you narrow it down (using the edit button) underneath it to a single specific question?

Comment: We removed and redacted the names that were not clearly compliant with our Privacy Policy in the [help/on-topic].  Please do not restore them unless you are able to provide links (as described in the policy) that can support that they are deceased.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that your father came from [NovoSibirsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novosibirsk), which appears to be "the third-most populous city in Russia (after Moscow and St. Petersburg)", it seems likely that it would have people there interested in the family history of its current and former residents.

When I searched on "Novosibirsk family history" I found that there is a [Novosibirsk Russia Family History Center](https://www.worldcat.org/libraries/137659).  This is their address and email:

```
Krasnly Prospect, 79/1 4th floor
Novosibirsk,  630049 
Russian Federation
Email: RU_Novosibirsk@ldsmail.net
```

You could write/email them and enquire after anyone named Chevtaikin in their holdings.